# If the size of sitemap is limited: how do I tell to Google all of my URLs?

Tags: google, sitemap

I [heard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sitemaps) that the sitemap for Google can not exceed 10 Mb and 50 kURLs. This is not enough for me. What shell I do to pass through this obstacle? Create sitemap for each category?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use [Sitemap index files](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#index):

> You can provide multiple Sitemap files, but each Sitemap file that you
>   provide must have no more than 50,000 URLs and must be no larger than
>   10MB (10,485,760 bytes). If you would like, you may compress your
>   Sitemap files using gzip to reduce your bandwidth requirement; however
>   the sitemap file once uncompressed must be no larger than 10MB. If you
>   want to list more than 50,000 URLs, you must create multiple Sitemap
>   files.
>
> If you do provide multiple Sitemaps, you should then list each Sitemap
>   file in a Sitemap index file. Sitemap index files may not list more
>   than 50,000 Sitemaps and must be no larger than 10MB (10,485,760
>   bytes) and can be compressed. You can have more than one Sitemap index
>   file. The XML format of a Sitemap index file is very similar to the
>   XML format of a Sitemap file.
>
> The Sitemap index file must:
>
> - Begin with an opening `<sitemapindex>` tag and end with a closing `</sitemapindex>` tag.
> - Include a `<sitemap>` entry for each Sitemap as a parent XML tag.
> - Include a `<loc>` child entry for each `<sitemap>` parent tag.
> - The optional `<lastmod>` tag is also available for Sitemap index files.
>
> Note: A Sitemap index file can only specify Sitemaps that are found on
>   the same site as the Sitemap index file. For example,
>   http://www.yoursite.com/sitemap_index.xml can include Sitemaps on
>   http://www.yoursite.com but not on http://www.example.com or
>   http://yourhost.yoursite.com. As with Sitemaps, your Sitemap index
>   file must be UTF-8 encoded.